# Help needed to solve a problem

Tags: functions

Suppose  $f(x+1)=2f(x),$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and in particular, $f(x)=x(x-1),$ for $0<x \leq 1.$

Could anyone advise me how to find $m$ such that $f(x) \geq -\dfrac{8}{9}$ for $x\leq m \ ?$ Do I need to find out the explicit form of $f \ ?$ Hints will suffice, thank you.

Comment: Are you sure that $f(x)= x(x-1)$ fulfills $f(x+1)=2f(x)$ ? I think the solution to $f(x+1)=2f(x)$ would be $f(x)=2^x$.

Comment: @Matti P.  I don't read the statement of the question as stating that $\ f(x+1) = 2f(x)\ $ for *all* $\ x\ $, but only for those $\ x\in (0, 1]\ $ for which $\ f(x)= x(x-1)\ $.  But if my interpretation is correct, it's difficult to see how the condition could be of any use in answering the question.  Both of the functions $\ f(x) = e^x\ $ and  $\ f(x) = -e^x\ $, for instance, would satisfy the condition, because for neither of them is there any $\ x\in (0,1]\ $ for which $\ f(x)=x(x-1)\ $.  I suspect some information is missing from the statement of the problem.

Comment: Hi, the phrasing of the question is ambiguous. I have amended accordingly.

Comment: Your title is uninformative.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we have $f(x+n) = 2^n f(x)$. So, all we have to do is find the values of $f(x)$ in $[0,1]$. Then we can scale the values to any value of $x\in\mathbb R$ we want.

Also, note that $f(x+1)\ge f(x)$ always.

In $[0,1]$, the minimum value of $f(x)$ is $\frac{-1}{4}$. As this is greater than $\frac{-8}{9}$, we can see that $\forall x \le 1$, your condition is satisfied.

Thus, all we need to see now is when will $2^n (\frac{-1}{4})$ be less than $\frac{-8}{9}$. This occurs for $n=2$. Hence, $m \in [2,3]$.

Now, we want an expression for $f(x)$ when $x\in [2,3]$. To see this, we take $x=t+2$, where $t\in [0,1]$. So, we have
\begin{align}
f(x) &= 4(x-2)\\
&=4f(t)\\
&=4t(t-1)\\
&=4(x-2)(x-3)
\end{align}

Now, we can find the points where $f(x)=\frac{-8}{9}$. The smaller of these will equal $m$.